# Geometric distribution with multiple success state and markovian succes probability

Tags: markov-process, geometric-distribution

Let $X_t$ be a random process in the space $E:=\{F, S_1, S_2, S_3\}$ for each $t$. We can see it like it is a game where we can win in three different ways or we can fail. We play until we fail for the first time. Let $M$ define the $3\times3$ success transition probability matrix :
$M = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13}\\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23}\\
p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$ where $p_{ij} = \mathbb{P}[X_t=S_j|X_{t-1} = S_i]$ and $\pi = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi_{1} & \pi_{2} & \pi_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$ be the initial probability i.e $\pi_{i} = \mathbb{P}[X_0=S_i]$.

I would like to determine the distribution of the number of time we win before failing. In other way, if we denote T this variable, we have :

$$\mathbb{P}[T=0] = 1-\pi_1-\pi_2-\pi_3$$

$$\mathbb{P}[T=1] = \pi_1.\mathbb{P}[X_1\in \{S_1,S_2,S_3\},X_2=F |X_0=S_1] +\\ \pi_2.\mathbb{P}[X_1\in \{S_1,S_2,S_3\},X_2=F |X_0=S_2] +\\
\pi_3.\mathbb{P}[X_1\in \{S_1,S_2,S_3\},X_2=F |X_0=S_3]\\
=\pi_1(p_{11} + p_{12} + p_{13})(1-p_{11} + p_{12} + p_{13}) + \\
\pi_2(p_{21} + p_{22} + p_{23})(1-p_{21} + p_{22} + p_{23}) + \\
\pi_3(p_{31} + p_{32} + p_{33})(1-p_{31} + p_{32} + p_{33})\\
\mathbb{P}[T=1] = \sum_{i=1}^3 \pi_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^3p_{ij}\right)\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^3p_{ij}\right)$$

It become very difficult to compute when $T\geq 2$.

Can you see how to compute it in a different way or is this similar to an existing distribution?

Thank you.

Comment: Include $F$ among your states, augment $M$ to include the transitions to it, and apply the standard Markov chain calculations.

Comment: In fact it I do so, I will have the time spend in each state $S_1, S_2, S_3$ or $F$. Me I want the time spend in {S_1, S_2, S_3}.

Comment: The relevant calculation is the chance that the system is in $F$ at time $T:$ from this you easily obtain the CDF of the time it took to reach $F.$

Comment: It helped me thanks. I will update the post when I'll obtain exactly what I wanted.